# Deselecting text with JavaScript doesn't remove blue bars on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, selection

I'm developing a bookmarklet that activates on text selection. On mobile iOS devices with touchscreens it has to remove blue bars marking this selection. So I try to deselect selected text and call `window.getSelection().empty()` or `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()`, but deselection doesn't help at all, blue bars are still visible on the screen.

So I made a test page with simple JavaScript code:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', function(e){
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.empty();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
});
</script>
```

- and it worked perfectly on desktop browsers. But when I open this page on iOS mobile Safari and select a word, blue bars are still inevitable (though text is properly deselected, I can neither copy a text nor expand the selection).

Can someone please help me, how can I remove these blue bars? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in Mobile Safari, sorry. You can change the selection if it's already visible but you I'm pretty sure you can't make the selection plus associated UI appear or disappear.